dpkg-buildpackage: Copying files to root directory when extracting the package using dpkg
I am trying to convert a static folder (does not have a makefile) into a ppa package using dpkg.
Below is my folder structure.
mypackage/
debian/
    rules
    copyright
    control
    source/file
    changelog
src/
    lib/firmware/
        a.fw
        b.fw
        c.fw
        d.fw
        
    License
    README
    

I have to package this folder and when extracting/installing this deb package using dpkg (sudo dpkg -i myPackage.deb) it should extract and copy the files a.fw b.fw c.fw and d.fw to /lib/firmware of the root folder of the target.
The following is my rules files:
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS := nofakeroot
DEBVERS := $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog | grep ^Version: | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d- -f1)
VERSION := $(shell echo '$(DEBVERS)' | sed -e 's/[+-].*//' -e 's/~//g')

DESTDIR := /lib/firmware
SRCDIR := $(CURDIR)/debian/MyPackage/usr/src/MyPackage-$(VERSION)

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_install:
        # Call the default dh_install
        mkdir -p $(SRCDIR)
        cp -a src/* $(SRCDIR)/
        # Copy firmware files to /lib/firmware/
        cp -r $(SRCDIR)/lib/firmware/*.fw $(DESTDIR)/
        dh_install

I use the below commands to package the source folder
dh_make --createorig --single --yes
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -sa -S
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -F

The packaging is complete and I can see the .fw files being copied to /lib/firmware/ . When I try to install it on the target hardware, The files do not get copied to target folder. I have inspected the .deb file generated to check if source files are present.
I have also tried keeping a mypackage.install file in debian folder which throws errors related to permissions. I am not able to resolve the issue. Can someone please point me a feasible solution for the same.
Thanks
